# Add a URL as filter criteria in Views

Tags: 7, views, media, uri, javascript

I have a page of content type insert which adds images to my website. It currently just displays images in rows when you click to view the **album name** pages.

I have installed [FlexSlider](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider) as I want to use that module to display all images  that are on pages that contain ***/Album/AlbumName*** in the URL  as a slideshow automatically. How do I do that in Views?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a content type which has a photo filed and you want to show the photos in the form of slider, Than I will suggest to use FlxSlider.

1. Go to your_seite/admin/structure/types/manage/your_content/display/
2. Change the photo filed form to flexslider
3. Click the setting icon to customize the slider options
4. Click Save

[image]

**If your want to have some sort of photo album** in your site than I will suggest to use [Juicebox HTML5 Responsive Image Galleries](https://www.drupal.org/project/juicebox)

This module provides an integration between the popular Juicebox HTML5 responsive gallery library and Drupal. Juicebox is in many ways the successor of Simpleviewer and offers a powerful cross-device solution for image galleries, sliders and more.